# Dynamic file download in Struts2

Tags: java, firefox, struts2, download

In my Struts2 application, i have the page that list of file names, cliking on that filename will download that file.here filename comes from db. for that i have coded like

```
<iterator list... 
<a href="filedownload.action?filepath=${filepath}>${filepath} </a>
</iterator...
```

in filedownload action i have written codes open filestream (struts2 filedownalod).

It is working in all browsers except Firefox7+. its throwing `**"Content correpted Error"**`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has some issue with URL encoding. I don't think it is good idea to pass path as parameter. It is safe to pass ID on the database to the action and download by FileInputStream. At least, you can check permission of user when it is about to download privileged files.

I would do like this:

```
<iterator list... 
<a href="filedownload?id=%{id_in_the_database} </a>
</iterator...
```

Action class

```
public String download() throws Exception {

    fileName = getFromDatabaseById(id);

    try
    {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_FOLDER + filename));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        logger.error(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": File in " + FILE_FOLDER + filename + " cannot be found.");
            return ERROR;
        }

        return DOWNLOAD;
}
```

And in your struts.xml

```
 <action name="filedownload" method="download" class="com.yourproject.filedownload">
    <result name="download" type="stream">
      <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
      <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
      <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=%{filename}</param>
      <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error" type="redirectAction">erroraction</result>
 </action>
```